# Syntax Error inside map, but works on the online webservice

Tags: java, plantuml

I'm trying to use plantuml inside java to generate a svg file. The code I'm using is basically the one from the example,

```
        byte[] bytes = source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String utf8EncodedString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(utf8EncodedString);
        SourceStringReader reader = new SourceStringReader(utf8EncodedString);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Write the first image to "os"
        reader.generateImage(os, new FileFormatOption(FileFormat.SVG));
        os.close();
        // The XML is stored into svg
        final String svg = new String(os.toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        return svg;
```

Basically the utf-8 stuff is because I was thinking the issue was with encoding, but it turns out it's not. The string used as source is as follows:

```
@startuml
left to right direction
' Horizontal lines: -->, <--, <-->
' Vertical lines: ->, <-, <->
map Transport.Personnel{
ID => 38
}
map Airplane1{
ID => 39
}
map Airplane2{
ID => 40
}
map Lathe1{
ID => 41
}
map Lathe2{
ID => 42
}
map Production.from.Mold1{
ID => 43
}
map Production.from.Mold2{
ID => 44
}
map Assembly.Line1{
ID => 45
}
map Assembly.Line2{
ID => 46
}
map Assembly.Line3{
ID => 47
}
@enduml
```

This string generates a diagram on the online plantuml web service but when running on java, the svg generated indicates a syntax error in the string when opening it up:

```
... (skipping 1 line) ...
left to right direction
' Horizontal lines:
-->, <--
, <-->
' Vertical lines: ->, <-, <->
map Transport.Personnel{
Syntax Error?
```

Do I need to do anything else? I really have no idea what could be going wrong and I don't know what to search here/their forums to try and debug.

Comment: What's the input `source` variable value? Where are you importing these classes from? Next time post minimal, REPRODUCIBLE code? I can't reproduce if I don't know which classes you are using.

Comment: @hfontanez source in this case is irrelevant, as I copy pasted the utf8EncodedString. The imports are from net.sourceforge.plantuml in the mvn repository. It works with the Bob-Alice string, as was the example I took this from

Comment: The input IS NOT irrelevant because it prevents me from running your code. I need to know the string value of the `source` variable in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @hfontanez then use the one I posted, it is the same. Or use `"@startuml\nleft to right direction\n\' Horizontal lines: -->, <--, <-->\n\' Vertical lines: ->, <-, <->\nmap Transport.Personel{\n ID => 15\n}\n@enduml\n"` which returns the same error on the svg

Comment: I was confused because you posted "The string printed out in the function above is as follows:" that sounds like an output to me. I will work on it to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: I ran what you posted and got no errors. The one in the comments results in a NullPointerException.

Comment: @hfontanez running the code is not the issue, it's the svg that is generated. The error is inside the svg. The plantuml server can generate a diagram with that string, but the java library using it cannot. I'll reformulate the question to be more specific

Comment: The output of my program and the output when running it online looks the same. When you generate the SVG, right click on the page and select "view source"

Comment: Review my answer. I do not see anything wrong since the output online and the output of the code appear to be the same. Let me know if my conclusion is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can this code which resulted in no errors for me

```
public class PlantUMLDemo {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        String source = "@startuml\r\n"
            + "left to right direction\r\n"
            + "' Horizontal lines: -->, <--, <-->\r\n"
            + "' Vertical lines: ->, <-, <->\r\n"
            + "map Transport.Personnel{\r\n"
            + "ID => 38\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Airplane1{\r\n"
            + "ID => 39\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Airplane2{\r\n"
            + "ID => 40\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Lathe1{\r\n"
            + "ID => 41\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Lathe2{\r\n"
            + "ID => 42\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Production.from.Mold1{\r\n"
            + "ID => 43\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Production.from.Mold2{\r\n"
            + "ID => 44\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Assembly.Line1{\r\n"
            + "ID => 45\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Assembly.Line2{\r\n"
            + "ID => 46\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "map Assembly.Line3{\r\n"
            + "ID => 47\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "@enduml";
        byte[] bytes = source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String utf8EncodedString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(utf8EncodedString);
        SourceStringReader reader = new SourceStringReader(utf8EncodedString);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Write the first image to "os"
        reader.generateImage(os, new FileFormatOption(FileFormat.SVG));
        os.close();
        // The XML is stored into svg
        final String svg = new String(os.toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(svg);
//      return svg;
    }
}
```

In case it is relevant, I used the latest PlantUML jar (version 1.2021.9). My assumption is that you probably made a syntax error in your code. Copy paste my source string and try again.

The output of the program is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="290px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:539px;height:290px;background:#FFFFFF;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 539 290" width="539px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="fxvmrbp5q73dl" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/></filter></defs><g><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="127" x="7" y="7"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="113" x="14" y="21.457">Transport.Personnel</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="7" x2="134" y1="26.0938" y2="26.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="12" y="38.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="32" y="38.4746">38</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="27" x2="27" y1="26.0938" y2="42.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="66" x="37.5" y="85"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="52" x="44.5" y="99.457">Airplane1</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="37.5" x2="103.5" y1="104.0938" y2="104.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="42.5" y="116.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="62.5" y="116.4746">39</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="57.5" x2="57.5" y1="104.0938" y2="120.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="66" x="37.5" y="163"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="52" x="44.5" y="177.457">Airplane2</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="37.5" x2="103.5" y1="182.0938" y2="182.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="42.5" y="194.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="62.5" y="194.4746">40</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="57.5" x2="57.5" y1="182.0938" y2="198.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="52" x="44.5" y="241"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="38" x="51.5" y="255.457">Lathe1</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="44.5" x2="96.5" y1="260.0938" y2="260.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="49.5" y="272.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="69.5" y="272.4746">41</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="64.5" x2="64.5" y1="260.0938" y2="276.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="52" x="252.5" y="7"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="38" x="259.5" y="21.457">Lathe2</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="252.5" x2="304.5" y1="26.0938" y2="26.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="257.5" y="38.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="277.5" y="38.4746">42</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="272.5" x2="272.5" y1="26.0938" y2="42.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="137" x="210" y="85"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="123" x="217" y="99.457">Production.from.Mold1</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="210" x2="347" y1="104.0938" y2="104.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="215" y="116.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="235" y="116.4746">43</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="230" x2="230" y1="104.0938" y2="120.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="137" x="210" y="163"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="123" x="217" y="177.457">Production.from.Mold2</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="210" x2="347" y1="182.0938" y2="182.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="215" y="194.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="235" y="194.4746">44</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="230" x2="230" y1="182.0938" y2="198.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="102" x="227.5" y="241"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="88" x="234.5" y="255.457">Assembly.Line1</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="227.5" x2="329.5" y1="260.0938" y2="260.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="232.5" y="272.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="252.5" y="272.4746">45</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="247.5" x2="247.5" y1="260.0938" y2="276.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="102" x="423" y="7"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="88" x="430" y="21.457">Assembly.Line2</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="423" x2="525" y1="26.0938" y2="26.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="428" y="38.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="448" y="38.4746">46</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="443" x2="443" y1="26.0938" y2="42.6719"/><rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fxvmrbp5q73dl)" height="35.6719" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="102" x="423" y="85"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="88" x="430" y="99.457">Assembly.Line3</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="423" x2="525" y1="104.0938" y2="104.0938"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="10" x="428" y="116.4746">ID</text><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="12" x="448" y="116.4746">47</text><line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="443" x2="443" y1="104.0938" y2="120.6719"/><!--MD5=[ff82272a54b0608060e06faff60c0c6f]
link Transport.Personnel to Airplane1--><!--MD5=[c202e95eecfc418b5501e2a8947e8feb]
link Airplane1 to Airplane2--><!--MD5=[636ba822349036c737d84d06f0729b92]
link Airplane2 to Lathe1--><!--MD5=[b9280dfb35d92cd40bcce7a3234b7f39]
link Transport.Personnel to Lathe2--><!--MD5=[771b27f758c2865dd959173aec72d1ef]
link Lathe2 to Production.from.Mold1--><!--MD5=[77de6294656f35161f6e03883c63e876]
link Production.from.Mold1 to Production.from.Mold2--><!--MD5=[73d5fa06c8330ee70fe1a2a0b8f7f067]
link Production.from.Mold2 to Assembly.Line1--><!--MD5=[8053d5220acde5e9c8d637bbcdec0086]
link Lathe2 to Assembly.Line2--><!--MD5=[b61908b6fd80267801bee0bc115ff909]
link Assembly.Line2 to Assembly.Line3--><!--MD5=[83bc2a7ae5b567adf58816b4879445c0]
@startuml
left to right direction
' Horizontal lines: - ->, <- -, <- ->
' Vertical lines: ->, <-, <->
map Transport.Personnel{
ID => 38
}
map Airplane1{
ID => 39
}
map Airplane2{
ID => 40
}
map Lathe1{
ID => 41
}
map Lathe2{
ID => 42
}
map Production.from.Mold1{
ID => 43
}
map Production.from.Mold2{
ID => 44
}
map Assembly.Line1{
ID => 45
}
map Assembly.Line2{
ID => 46
}
map Assembly.Line3{
ID => 47
}
@enduml

@startuml
left to right direction
map Transport.Personnel{
ID => 38
}
map Airplane1{
ID => 39
}
map Airplane2{
ID => 40
}
map Lathe1{
ID => 41
}
map Lathe2{
ID => 42
}
map Production.from.Mold1{
ID => 43
}
map Production.from.Mold2{
ID => 44
}
map Assembly.Line1{
ID => 45
}
map Assembly.Line2{
ID => 46
}
map Assembly.Line3{
ID => 47
}
@enduml

PlantUML version 1.2021.9(Sun Jul 25 05:13:56 CDT 2021)
(GPL source distribution)
Java Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Default Encoding: Cp1252
Language: en
Country: US
--></g></svg>
```

Screenshot of generated SVG online
[image]

When I generate this on the PLantUML website and I "view source", the results looks exactly like this output. I have to conclude that the code works with the provided `source` string value.

Comment: Yea, that output is what I was expecting. I still seem to be getting an error, even after copypasting that code and running it as a standalone. Would it be an issue with the jar? I'm using `<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.plantuml</groupId>
        <artifactId>plantuml</artifactId>
        <version>8059</version>
    </dependency>` on my pom

Comment: @AndréRocha Who knows? I would update to the latest jar which is the one I am using. All I did was run your posted code and your posted input String (as you can see from my post). Unless there is some typo on your IDE, there could be an issue with the version of the jar you are using. I would appreciate if you upvote and select my answer it this was helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, I updated to another jar. `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.plantuml/plantuml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.plantuml</groupId>
    <artifactId>plantuml</artifactId>
    <version>1.2020.14</version>
</dependency>` This one works properly, but I was confused because when I searched online the previous appeared first on the mvn repo, so I assumed it was the most recent. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréRocha Looks like you downgraded or is it a typo (1.2020.14)? anyway the latest release of plantuml is 1.2021.16 (see https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml) and theer are also "snapshot builds" that you can get with `wget --quiet https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/releases/download/snapshot/plantuml-SNAPSHOT.jar` (at the moment of writing this is version 1.2021.17beta3.

Comment: @albert actually Andre upgraded from version 8059 (March 2017) to 1.2020.16 (August 2020). But as I suggested to him, he should upgrade to the latest (1.2021.16). I used 1.2021.9 for this example because I thought it was the latest. But it is at least recent and it works. Also, I will never recommend anyone learning how to use a library to go to a beta version from the start. Unless you have previous experience with a library, you should ALWAYS use a stable version.

Comment: @hfontanez I agree with your statement about the stable version, but for completeness I gave also the snapshot link. The later might be useful for other, more experienced, users as well.

Comment: @albert I just wanted to make clear that beta versions are for experienced developers. I know you are not a cruel human being. LOL